# HTTP Error 404.0 -Not Found The resource looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable at .Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, crystal-reports

Tried every possible solution provided in internet, still the issue is not resolved.
[image]

Comment: what is the issue ? is the file exist and not load it ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means page or content is not found that you are looking for. First make sure that, page is available that you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

What solutions have you tried? you can try to add the following code to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you published the project to IIS or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).